# Comparing elements in a list and ignoring white space

Tags: functions, string-manipulation

I have two lists with element entries.   I want Mathematica to identify an element in an opposing list such as Ag107 to be the same as Ag 107 ignoring any space. Each different element occurs only a single time in an individual list. I am comparing lists to see what elements they share. They are pulled in from csv so I am not sure if they are classified as strings or whether I need to convert them to strings in Mathematica. Unfortunately the two lists have inconsistent naming conventions within the list themselves, so the individual lists use a mixture of spaces and no spaces. I am using functions such as Complement, Position, ContainsExactly, MemberQ.

Comment: Example data and the code of what you tried would help a lot.

Comment: OK, I have just discover I can apply StringDelete and remove white spaces from both lists. This works for me.  Shall I withdraw the question?

Comment: You can always post an answer to your own question

Answer (score 2):

I found the function `StringDelete`, and removed white spaces from all elements in the lists.

I seem to be using `& /@` frequently to thread over the list.

```
speciesList = StringDelete[speciesList[[#]], " "] & /@ Range[Length[speciesList]];
```

Comment: We could also use `StringDelete[" "] /@ speciesList`.